# Ionic cannot find my controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to integrate a side menu into my already existing app. So that means that I have to change how my controllers are setup. I added a menu controller, but the app keeps throwing me this error:

`Argument 'MenuCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`

Here is my old app.js file:

```js
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 $stateProvider
   .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })

    .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
    //controller: 'LoginCtrl'
   })

   .state('messaging', {
    url: '/messaging',
    templateUrl: 'templates/messaging.html'
    //controller: 'MessageCtrl'
 })

    .state('equipment', {
        url: '/equipment',
        templateUrl: 'templates/equipment.html'
    })

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
})
```

Then I made these changes to setup my side menu:

```js
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 $stateProvider

   .state('app', {
      url: '/app',
      templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
      controller: 'MenuCtrl'
    })

   .state('app.home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })

    .state('app.login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
    //controller: 'LoginCtrl'
   })

   .state('app.messaging', {
    url: '/messaging',
    templateUrl: 'templates/messaging.html'
    //controller: 'MessageCtrl'
 })

    .state('app.equipment', {
        url: '/equipment',
        templateUrl: 'templates/equipment.html'
    })



 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
})
```

That is where i get the above error. I have created a MenuCtrl.js and set it up like this:

```js
angular.module('App')

.controller('MenuCtrl', function () {

})
```

I do not understand why it cannot find the controller. Ive done it just like all my other controllers. It is driving me insane!

Thanks in advance stack.

Comment: Did you include `MenuCtrl.js` in your `index.html`?

Comment: Wow rookie mistake.. wow. Leave an answer, Ill accept it. Just wow.. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have forgotten to include `MenuCtrl.js` in your `index.html`. Right now Angular doesn't know how to find the controller, because it is not being loaded.